# Почему у меня не открывается редактирование страницы после того как я включаю асинхронную загрузку. (wordpress) (js)

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

```
function wcs_defer_javascripts ( $url ) {
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
    if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
    return "$url' async='async";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'wcs_defer_javascripts', 11, 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у вас ошибка с кавычками:

```
return "$url' async='async";
```